# Qt Application Appearance Running Over Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, qt, rdp

I work on a desktop application that we sometimes have to run on a virtual machine using Windows Remote Desktop for access. Fonts and gradients are noticeably degraded in appearance when running through Remote Desktop. The fonts are clearly not anti-aliased (and are normally) The gradients degenerate into much larger bands of solid color, losing the smoother look. Initially, I had assumed Windows was doing this to improve performance, but when I compared application fonts in our produce with those in other applications (Visual Studio specifically), I see that Qt is definitely rendered fonts in dialogs and `QGraphicsScene` differently.

In the application title bar of my app, I see that the font exactly matches the appearance of other application title bars, and that makes sense because Windows draws that. Within my application, all of the top menu items and fonts on dialogs are not anti-aliased and look terrible. We use `QGraphicsScene` extensively, and those fonts are degraded as well.

I don't have another application that generates gradients to compare those, but I viewed a high resolution image through the Remote Desktop connection using the Windows image viewer, and it looks just as good as on a local desktop.

The degraded appearance means that we can't do screen shots for documentation while using the VM. We are also frequently required to do demos using VMs and Remote Desktop, and the appearance is not appealing to show to customers. In our industry and within our company, there's increasing pressure to use VMs instead of local, physical machines, so this is becoming a bigger problem.

Both symptoms lead me to believe that Qt knows that I'm visualizing through Remote Desktop and that it is choosing to degrade appearance in favor of performance. I don't want that, or at the very least, I need to control it.

I suspect this is buried somewhere in Qt's style/theme system, but I haven't had any luck finding clues that would point me to the correct place to do something about this, or at least an answer that indicates whether or not it's even possible. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to address the issue with fonts in QGraphicsScene. Because of the nature of our product, the font handling for graphics items was fairly specialized, and very early in development when I was very new to Qt, I had set the style strategy to those fonts to QFont::ForceOutline because I didn't want the font matching to use any bitmapped fonts. Through experimentation, I found that this strategy results in the fonts not being anti-aliased when running through Remote Desktop. Changing to QFont::PreferAntialias addressed the problem for the fonts in the scene, and that's a substantial and welcome improvement.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a solution for the general application fonts, nor for the gradient degradation, but at least with the fonts, I have something more to go on. My next step will be to start inspecting the fonts that Qt is using by default on some of the widgets and seeing what their attributes are.

Comment: Revisited this and not sure why I thought the issue would be different with the scene versus the rest of the app, but the fix is to apply the QFont::PreferAntialias font strategy to every font we use. We have set an application-wide font, and setting the strategy on that corrected most of the application. There were a few other isolated instances where I had to fix up a font instance, but it all looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

With `QGraphicScene` we have OpenGL for rendering. And with some of VMs we mostly rely on software simulating OpenGL via MS DirectX, which is for software and not hardware supported rendering. The most popular software OpenGL rendering is based on [ANGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANGLE_(software)).

To improve the rendering on VM I would try to build a custom Qt for your app using one of proposed [Qt build configurations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#graphics-drivers) to configure specific Windows Qt build.

With Qt evolving it gets a bit confusing: which configuration is the best. I was told that since Qt 5.5 `-opengl dynamic` will be an optimal for most of environments. I used to configure `-opengl es2` configuration with Qt 5.3 and that worked well without degrading the graphics but mind that VMs used are from VMware and not MS Hyper-V that would not even allow the app to load due to OpenGL failing to initialize and I could not make [ANGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANGLE_(software)) to help here with that specific Qt.

Comment: "With QGraphicScene we have OpenGL for rendering" - Only if it's configured like that.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I guess if it is not configured like that then the graphics are not as good. BTW, how to configure it for not using OpenGL? I mean not even ANGLE.

Comment: If the problem were limited to QGraphicsScene, I could see this as a solution, but it's all aspects of the application...fonts on top-level menus, on dialog boxes, and so on. All of it is degraded, but only in our Qt application, not in other Windows programs. Changing to OpenGL rendering (which may not be viable for us) for the scene isn't going to help the rest. My hunch is that this is something in the style system, and that Qt is detecting the Remote Desktop connection and choosing different styling options. Any ideas in that area?

Comment: For me all the non-OpenGL UI items are not affected by VM at all. At least what I am seeing with available VMs and hearing from customer complaints.

Comment: I neglected to mention that we're using Qt 5.4.1. AlexanderVX, what Qt version are you using? And I'm wondering if the Windows version matters. We're on Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1 on both the remote and local sides.

Comment: @goug, Qt 5.3.2 static build with -opengl -es2 The remote side either Windows Server 2012 or VDI with Windows 8.1 or 10. Windows 7 on remote side is probably an issue because OpenGL is not a part of it yet the emulation like ANGLE needs the DirectX. Try to check on DirectX available on your remote side.

Comment: Event fonts are degrading? Could that be Smart Sizing responsible? If so, I can easily imaging that. So I don't consider the case with Smart Sizing as eligible - it is natural for graphics to degrade via the bitmap transformation.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with Smart Sizing so I looked it up. We're on Windows 7, and the site I found indicates that Smart Sizing wasn't turned on by default, and that you have to manually edit an RDP file to do it, which I haven't done. Also, both the Remote Desktop and my local desktop are at the same resolution, so I'm not sure that would be a factor. I will definitely do some experimenting with this though.

Comment: Hmm... Smart Sizing is an attribute of Remote Desktop Windows client software and be checked either by right clicking on the remote window title bar or in that window context men while not full screen.

Comment: According to the information I found about Smart Sizing is that the feature you mentioned became available in Windows 8. We are on Windows 7 and it's definitely not there. Since it's not turned on by default in Windows 7, I don't believe it's contributing to this problem. Again, my hunch is that the problem is related to something Qt is doing internally.

Comment: Smart Sizing was not introduced during Windows 7 release year but then became available for newer Remote Desktop installed via Service Pack etc. Anyway, my interest in that if we face that same problem and why you get it and we can only see the picture distorted while using Smart Sizing.